# Why is my Web Api increasing memory usage at every request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I coded a web api that only returns data from a get method, but at every request I make, it increases the RAM usage by almost 100MB. This would be a problem if it's running on a server and receiving a lot of requests.
Here's my Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var options = new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    ContentRootPath = WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService() ? AppContext.BaseDirectory : default
};

builder.Host.UseWindowsService();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.Urls.Add("http://*:5436");

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And here is the only controller:

```
using Npgsql;

namespace F360Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class PedidoController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public PedidoController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _config = configuration;
        }

        private List<Dictionary<string, object>> ExecuteQuery(string query, NpgsqlParameter[] parameters = null)
        {
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> result = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

            string sqlDataSource = _config.GetConnectionString("F360Api");

            using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    if (parameters != null)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                    }

                    using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            var row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                            {
                                row[reader.GetName(i)] = reader[i];
                            }
                            result.Add(row);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                string query = @""; --query here

                List<Dictionary<string, object>> result = ExecuteQuery(query);

                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        [HttpGet("GetByDate")]
        public IActionResult GetByDate([FromQuery] DateTime startDate, [FromQuery] DateTime endDate)
        {
            try
            {
                string query = @""; --query here

                NpgsqlParameter[] parameters =
                {
                    new NpgsqlParameter("@startDate", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp) { Value = startDate },
                    new NpgsqlParameter("@endDate", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp) { Value = endDate }
                };

                List<Dictionary<string, object>> result = ExecuteQuery(query, parameters);

                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Already tried caching data, but no success.

Comment: I don't see anything too suspicious from the code included here, but you should probably get a [diagnostic report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour?view=vs-2022). They aren't the easiest to understand sometimes but they will show you info on what's being allocated in memory

Comment: Can you check the number of the open connections on the database?
I do not know Npgsql, and your code seems properly disposing the connections, commands and readers it uses. Maybe the Npgsql driver explicitly requires a .close() call on the connections?

Comment: How many rows are read on this query? If you have read many rows, it uses a lot of memory or increases.

Comment: After some days trying to figure this thing out still no clue why memory keeps increasing. Used cache, GC.Collect, eventhough didn't need it, but memory keeps increasing. I'm really stressing the reader since I'm getting data from 2001 until today. It's not gonna be like on the daily usage, but it got me thinking if I develop bigger APIs in the future and the same problem keeps happening.